# basic help scheduling stored proc in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks, sql-agent

I am new to SQL server but have been in IT for a  long time.  I need to schedule a stored procedure to execute on schedule periodically, and I am pretty sure I have the steps wrong.

The code is good, having been tested extensively.

1. The **procedure** is listed in the Programmability folder in the correct database
2. I created a **Job** in SQL Server Agent called `TestInvoiceTransCode` that has 1 step called Start, type of Transact SQL script, no 'Run as', and the command is `EXEC ZZproc_InvoiceTransCode`
3. It is attached to a **schedule** called `TransCodeTest` that is enabled, and set to `recurring, executing every minute`.
4. Under Activity Monitor, the `TestInvoiceTransCode` job lists as **enabled**, **idle**, with **never** as last run.

All this setup was done when logged in as **sa** user.  I do not have access to the OS, so I can't verify which processes are running.

This is all in a DEV environment which is an exact mirror of PROD.

Are there any steps I missed?

Thanks

.... I'll bet this is a good clue.  As Steve suggested I tried to manually launch the job and got a message suggesting that the Agent is not running.  I am reaching out to the sys admins to let me know if that is the issue, but could this message indicate another issue?

[Error when starting job manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF9TO.jpg)

Comment: Add schedule window screenshot to your question.

Comment: What happens when you perform an ad-hoc run of the job? (right click on job, start job at step)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the advice, the problem was related to the SQL Server Agent not starting in the DEV environment.  The problem was at the OS level and has been rectified.